# loading CanVec directory full of .shp files

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes

I'm totally new to QGIS, and trying to view a Canadian Topo map **as published** on an iMac - I don't want to change it.

http://www.geogratis.ca/geogratis/en/option/select.do?id=5460AA9D-54CD-8349-C95E-1A4D03172FDF&datasets=031g05

1. the directory contains a lot of files - can all be loaded in one go so I get the whole map, not just pieces of it?
2. the CanVec attributes (colour, symbol etc.) aren't retrieved when loading a shape file with vector load, so that doesn't work to see it the way the map maker intended.

I suspect these problems are related, in that there's a file somewhere that lets QGIS tie everything together, but I can't figure out what it is or how to tell QGIS how to use it.

Comment: @johnsankey: you have two logins; see http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Answer (score 2):

1. The shapefiles could all be loaded in one operation, but will you need all of them for your project?
2. As the name suggests, shapefiles contain shapes; points, lines or polygons. It's up to you, the map maker, to decide what "style" you wish to apply to the shapes. The [manual](http://docs.qgis.org/pdf/QGIS-1.8-UserGuide-en.pdf) will tell you how to do this.

The meaning of the shapefile names in your dataset is shown in [this Excel file](http://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/canvec/doc/CanVec_EntitiesCodesFileNames_EntitesCodesNomsDeFichier_v1_1_3.xls).

If you are an absolute beginner it would be a good idea to work through the example project shown in the manual.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've now heard from the Canada Centre for Topographic Information - there is no 'context' file for the CanVec maps other than one for the version of ArcGIS used internally at CCTIC. If I'm to use the CanVec data, I will indeed have to render it myself and just imitate the published maps as best I can.